# Compare data from last two dates in MySQL - DB

Tags: mysql

Consider a table with data as

```
SomeID   Date        SomeData
1        2014-07-29  SomeNumber1
2        2014-07-29  SomeNumber2
1        2014-07-30  SomeNumber3
2        2014-07-30  SomeNumber4
```

I wish to compare the data of one ID with the data of another ID for the last two dates as in the two most recent dates. How do I select data identified uniquely by an ID and a Date for the two most recent dates. The eventual result would be something like

`SomeNumber1 - SomeNumber3`
`SomeNumber2 - SomeNumber4`

and so on...

Comment: Funny indeed :) Although I hardly put in any effort I copied the template from meta ;)

Comment: There is actually no way to make a table. U can format it though.

Comment: @fancyPants FYI http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128302 :)

Comment: Yeah read them. Had time on hand.. Don't get too worked up about it though it was meant to mock stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are always sequential you could try something like this:

```
select a.SomeData - b.SomeData from MyTable a, MyTable b
where a.SomeID = b.SomeID and b.Date = DATE_ADD(a.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

But you`ll probably want to skip weekend and such, in which case it gets much more complicated (using incremental columns for instance)

Comment: As I said it should only be for the last two dates this would give me all one day differences.

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant two consecutive dates.Try adding: AND b.Date IN (SELECT MAX(Date), DATE_SUB(MAX(Date),INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM MyTable)